# Binding ICommand WPF ObservableCollection DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

I'm trying to get a WPF MVVM template to work with the basic functionality I am doing in a WPF but non MVVM application.  In this case I am trying to capture the RowEditEnding event (which I am) to validate the data on the row that has changed (and this is the problem).

In the XAML I have used an event trigger:

```
        <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding oDoc.View}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="docIDColumn" Binding="{Binding DocId}" Header="ID" Width="65"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="DocumentNumberColumn" Binding="{Binding Number}" Header="Document Number" Width="*"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="altIDColumn" Binding="{Binding AltID, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Header="Alt" Width="55"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="RowEditEnding">
                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding DocRowEdit}"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </DataGrid>
```

With a delegate command to rout to the handler:

```
        public ObservableCollection<Document> oDoc
    {
        get
        {
            return _oDoc;
        }
    }

    public ICommand DocRowEdit
    {
        get { return new DelegateCommand(DocumentRowEditEvent); }
    }

    public void DocumentRowEditEvent()
    {
        //How do I find the changed item?
        int i = 1;
    }
```

I have not found a way to find the member of the ObservableCollection (oDoc) that has pending changes.  I notice that the datagrid is doing some validation, the AltID field that I want to change will highlight red if I put in a non numeric value.  But I want to handle the validation, and associated messaging myself.  What am I missing?  I was thinking to somehow raise a property changed event, but don't find how to wire something like this in:

```
        protected void RaisePropertyChangedEvent(string propertyName)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
```

The last two code blocks are from my ViewModel class, and I'm trying to do this without any code behind, aside from instantiating the ViewModel in the MainWindow constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a property to your ViewModel:

```
public Document CurrentDocument
{
    get
    {
        return _currentDocument;
    }
    set
    {
        if (value != _currentDocument)
        {
            _currentDocument = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("CurrentDocument") // If you implement INotifyPropertyChanged
        }
    }
}
```

and then you can bind it to SelectedItem property of your DataGrid:

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding oDoc.View}" SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentDocument}">
```

Therefore your edit method will be:

```
public void DocumentRowEditEvent()
{
    CurrentDocument.Number = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
    /* And so on... */
}
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Ok, great.  This binding is very powerful.  Relative to the OnPropertyChanged, I also implemented that, and I'm not sure if I totally grasp what that does.  It seems that it simply fires an event, and if I want to handle that event I will need to add another event trigger to the XAML block in the datagrid.  Is that right?  Or is there another way to capture that in a handler?  I used it in the debugger and saw my OnPropertyChanged function get called, which did `handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));`, but I don't grok how to use that.

Comment: I agree, it is a powerfull tool! Regardins `OnPropertyChanged` event (i.e. `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface), it is not a simple mechanism to fire an event. Indeed it allows your UI to be aware about data changes performed by code. You can read more either [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695(v=vs.110).aspx) or on [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29054/WPF-Data-Binding-Part).